# Php MSQLI query function

Tags: php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$keyId = $_POST['keyid'];
$verificationCode = $_POST['verificationcode'];
$accessMask = $_POST['accessmask'];
$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'Web', 'pass', 'Account_Information');

if ($connection->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Connection failed [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
}

$usernameresults = $connection->query("SELECT `Username` FROM `Members_Information` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");

while ($row = $Usernameresults->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['Username'] === $username) {
        echo "Username has already been choosen";
    }
    echo $row['Username'];
}
```

This is my current code which is retrieving and echoing the correct information. What I would like to do is if possible is to put the while loop into a function?
The object the code executes is to verify that a username is not already in the database. I would like to do this as a function or anther option so I can next verify that the email is also not in the database.

I would prefer to stay using MSQLI .

Comment: What happens when you try to put the code into a function?  Does it fail in some way?  (Also, what is the point of the `WHERE` clause in your query?)

Comment: you're doing the equivalent of going to a grocery store, buying the ENTIRE stock of the store, driving it home, and then throwing away everything except the chocolate bar you wanted. You **REALLY** need to learn about `where` clauses in SQL, and probably about [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com)  vulnerabilities as well.

Comment: @MarcB I quickly snatched that chocolate bar. Now they're left with nothing.

Comment: Use parameterized queries and have the DB tell you if the username is in use. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @David when i went to phpmyadmin and worked out the query for the information it added it. I believe it means if there's a value display it.

Comment: @MarcB am i able to use a varible in the where section ?

Comment: @JamesGerstenberg: It doesn't mean anything unless there's an actual condition being checked.  You're selecting every row in the table.  If you only want a specific row (or specific subset of rows) then create an actual `WHERE` clause.  Something like `WHERE Username = ?` and then use parameter binding to set the `$username` value to that query parameter.

Comment: @chris85 neither of those work for my setup ive tried to set it up but the code keeps failing so I gave up with that route

Comment: Post what you tried and how it failed (error message?).

Comment: @chris85 Ive already removed it as ive gone a different route but it was not showing me anything in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `Members_Information` WHERE `Username`='".$username."'");


$row = $Usernameresults->fetch_row()) {
if($row[0] > 0 ){
 echo "Username has already been choosen";
}
echo $row['Username'];
}
```

Comment: You just introduced a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You should reconsider how you are writing your queries. This is bad practice.

Comment: OK, i only wanted to transport the idea of using count() for this.It does not need a result-loop since it returns 1 row